# Как передать в Python значение int копией в функцию?

Tags: python, ооп, функции, методы, процедуры

Мне надо передать в функцию в Python значение не ссылкой, а копией. Как мне это реализовать? Метод `copy.copy(val)` ситуацию не изменяет. Информации в интернете по этому поводу не нашел.

```
def Quicksort(InList, l, r):
    if(l < r): 
        q = __Partition(InList, l, r)
        Quicksort(InList, l, q) // Вот тут проблема: q модифицируется, а надо, чтобы оно не изменялось
        Quicksort(InList, q + 1, r) // В этой функции далее возникает ошибка из-за модификации в предыдущей.
```

Comment: qq = q      Quicksort(InList, l, qq)

Comment: @MBo Извините, можно более развёрнутый ответ?

Comment: Просто скопируйте значение в новую переменную и используйте её при вызове.

Comment: @MBo Спасибо, но, к, сожалению, всё еще значение передается по ссылке. Ситуация не изменилась.

Comment: Как воспроизвести ?  https://onlinegdb.com/KU2or3SxW